# How to connect to local mariadb server with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, fedora

I'm trying to connect to a local mariadb server using node.js. When I try connecting I get the error:

"Error: (conn=8, no: 1045, SQLState: 28000) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

I am not sure why this is, as I have the password set when I make the connection, and I can log into the mysql server using the root password with

```
 mysql -u root -p
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
var mysql = require('mariadb');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "8pJcpe/h0h_%",
        port: 3306
        })
        .then(conn => {
                console.log("connected" + conn.threadId);
        })
        .catch(err => {
                console.log("got error " + err);
        });
```

I have also tried it with port 3307, and get this error:
"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307"

When I try to use the port I am using to ssh into the server, I get this different error:
" Error: (conn=-1, no: 45009, SQLState: 08S01) socket has unexpectedly been closed"

I am new to this and I could use some help. Thanks.

Comment: What version of the MariaDB Node.js connector has this problem not providing the `password` ?

Answer (score 0):

Some key ideas:

- MySQL user is identified by user *and* host.
- In MySQL `localhost` means local socket connection, not TCP/IP loopback.

This:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

is going to use local socket connection; this will match mysql.user table row `user='root' and host='localhost'`

To force a TCP/IP connection:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

This will match a row in mysql.user such as `user='root' and host='127.0.0.1'`, or `user='root' and host='%'`

Each row in mysql.user is a separate user; there can be multiple rows with `user='root'` and different values of `host`. Each of these rows represents separate users, each with its own privileges and password (or authentication method).

---

For the mariadb node.js driver

using `host` option, we are going to attempt a TCP/IP connection.

To get a connection via the local socket file  (i.e. equivalent to `mysql -u root -p`,  we need to use `socketPath` rather than `host` option.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/nodejs-connection-options/

---

If we want to get a TCP/IP connection working in node.js, then we should first make sure that the `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` connection is working.

Comment: Thank you for this. It definitely clears some thing up but I am still not getting a result. First thing I tried was making sure I could log in with the TCP/IP connecting "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p" and I could. So then I changed my code, so that the host was "127.0.0.1", and when I ran that I got the same error message as before. I also tried to use 'socketPath' instead of 'host', and used the path that I found in the my.cnf file but that also did not work and I got the same error as before also.

Comment: The body of the error message "`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`" seems to indicate that a password was not provided. And the user `@'localhost'` makes it appear that it was a local socket connection (rather than TCP/IP) that was attempted. So I'm confused. Can we get the mysql command line client to issue the same error? omitting a password issuing just `mysql -u root` ?  (we should be able to get an error `using password: YES` if we provide a wrong password.)

Comment: One other thing we might try is following the coding pattern demonstrated in the MariaDB knowledge base, using `createPool` and `getConnection`   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/getting-started-with-the-nodejs-connector/

Comment: So by just doing `mysql -u root` I get the ` Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` response. But if I try to login and provide a wrong password I do get the `(using password: YES)` response. I just tried it again with the TCP/IP connection to make sure: `var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        user: "root",
        password: "8pJcpe/h0h_%",
        port: 3306`
and this spits out the error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: And I just tried using the pool method they showed but got the same errors unfortunatley

Comment: So as I suggested earlier, the error message is the one we expect when a password isn't provided. Based on the code shown in the question, we'd expect a password to be passed. I would check the matched row in mysql.user and verify that `plugin='mysql_native_password', verify the authentication string matches the return from `SELECT PASSWORD('mypassword')`, and also check the `password_expired`,  `account_locked` columns.  If it's possible DML changes were applied to the mysql.user table, we can issue a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` statement to force MySQL to re-read the tables. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. For some reason when using mariadb it would not recognize that I was providing it a password. So  I had to switch to to mysql and use that instead, and then I was able to connect and query the database.